# Chrome extension popup doesn't load resources

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup that shows a JQuery UI button, when I click on extension icon and popup shows up, it has the button with no theme applied, but if I do Inspect on the popup page and click again it shows properly, as if resources wouldn't be loaded when I click regularly. Any ideas please?

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <a id="btn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../options/options.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**options.js**

```
$("#btn").button();
$("#btn").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Button clicked");
});
```

Comment: Viktor, it works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/z0w65jq7. Probably not loading the `options.js` script? Add `console.log('Loaded options.js')` to the top of the file to make sure that it's loaded. By the way, you could safely remove `type="text/javascript"` and `charset="UTF-8"` in HTML5. Place above your `<html>` tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.
`

Comment: That was 1st thing I tried - options.js is working, if I click on the button it writes into the log.

Answer (score 0):

As Ilia kindly pointed out in the comment above, there's apparently something specific with charset and specifics of extension api, however it worked when I specified charset for the css explicitly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" charset="UTF-8">
```

Thanks to Ilia